# How to refresh all activity from one activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

I have multiple fragments with its activity.

When I refresh in MainActivity, I want all fragment's activity to refresh as well. Because I work with database and it involves refreshing others fragments to update the data.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
      // refreshing MainActivity only
      // I don't know how to call fragment's activity here

      swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
}
```

Comment: Why you want to refresh any other activity from current activity?

Comment: I have same question like @PriyankaRajput . My answer for this question is use broadcast receiver in all activity and make sure that it wont result crash. also even you refresh in background user can see the result only on navigation to particular screen. So that also achieved via on resume

Comment: Can't you use an observer on each fragment and get notified when the data on the database changes?

Comment: This sounds like there is a fundamental design problem. If these different UI components are using the same data model, they should each observe it directly instead of communicating back and forth between each other to find out the latest state of the data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment is dependent on activity and activity is not dependent on fragment. What you do in activity will affect the fragment. Do use this a starting point to look up.

Answer (score -1):

In the activity, you can call `recreate()` to `"recreate"` the activity **(API 11+)**

or you can use this for refreshing an Activity from within itself.

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Comment: That is not a solution. That's a hack